# How to get a VBA Class code execute only on one single instance of an Object?

Tags: excel, vba, class, scope, instance

Below is a simplified code for which I cannot explain the behavior. I am using 3 different classes. An object `Dot`, and object `cls_Trace` and an object `cls_DataSet` containing one array called `AllTraces()`

In `cls_DataSet` I call a sub of the object `cls_Trace`. That `Corners` Sub uses 1 `Dot` contained in an object of type `tDot`. The sub pertain to One(1) only instance of object `Trace`. Yet, after execution of One(1) only call from One(1) only object `Trace` all other objects `Trace` stored in the array `AllTraces()` will be affected the same.

That Sub `Corners` is supposed to edit values XY for the `Dot` object `UpperLeft` and `LowRight` contained its unique variable `myTrace`. Yet, after execution, All single `Trace` in the array `AllTraces()` have now inherited the values attributed to that one single `Trace` object.

Could that be a VBA subtle bug? Or a subtle bug in my code (most probably)? Yet, I've spent hours trying to find where could the problem be.

---

In class definition named `cls_DataSet`

```
Dim AllTraces() As cls_Trace  

Public Sub CreateInterDot()
    Dim i As Long
    SpreadCount = 30
    CNT = UBound(AllTraces)
    For i = 3 To CNT - 1
       PointAddress = AllTraces(i).LPo
       BezelCount = SpreadCount - 1

       Call DebugAllDots
       Call AllTraces(PointAddress).Corners(AllTraces(PointAddress - 1).LXY, True)
       Call DebugAllDots
       Call AllTraces (PointAddress).Corners(AllTraces (PointAddress).LXY, False)
       Call DebugAllDots
    Next i
End Sub
```

In class definition named `cls_Trace`

```
Private Type tDot
    Po As Long
    Ra As Double
    CT As clsDot        ' Center XY value
    XY As clsDot        ' XY value for this point
    UperLeft As clsDot  ' One Dot define the Upper Left  corner
    LowRight As clsDot  ' One Dot define the Lower Right
End Type

Dim myTrace As tDot
Dim X As Double, Y As Double

Property Get LXY() As cls__Dot        ' Server for the Dot object
    Set LXY = myTrace.XY
End Property

Public Sub Corners(DotOne As cls__Dot, First As Boolean)
    With myTrace
        X = DotOne.XY(Y)
        If First Then
            Let .UperLeft.XY(Y) = X:     Let .LowRight.XY(Y) = X
            ULX = X: ULY = Y: LRX = X: LRY = Y
        Else
            ULX = IIf(X < ULX, X, ULX): ULY = IIf(Y > ULY, Y, ULY)  ' Upper
            LRX = IIf(X > LRX, X, LRX): LRY = IIf(Y < LRY, Y, LRY)  ' Lower
            Let .UperLeft.XY(ULY) = ULX:     Let .LowRight.XY(LRY) = LRX
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

In class definition named `cls__Dot`

```
Private Type XY
    X As Double     ' X value for the point
    Y As Double     ' Y value for the point
End Type

Dim MyXY As XY

Property Let XY(Y As Double, X As Double)   ' Assigne les valeurs X Y au point
    MyXY.X = X: MyXY.Y = Y
End Property

Property Get XY(Y As Double) As Double     ' Serveur X Y de ce point
    XY = MyXY.X: Y = MyXY.Y
End Property
```

in `cls_DataSet` this `Corners` Sub is called with one variable of type `cls__Dot`

```
Call AllTraces(PointAddress).Corners(AllTraces(PointAddress - 1).LXY, True)
```

More simply it would look like this

```
call MyTrace.Corners(MyDot, True)
```

In the Debug code I list all 25 objects `Traces` XY values as well as XY values of `UpperLeft` and `LowerRight`. In all I can see all XY values of 3 Dots recorded in each instance of a Trace. In total that is 25 x 6 values in the VBA Debug window.

At each iteration of `i` I will read all those 150 values. XY will always remain the same since they are the original data. Each 25 lines will show the XY value for each `Dot`. But at each iteration of `i`, the `Dot` values of `UpperLeft` and `LowerRight` will change, but all 25 object will see its `LowerRight` and `Upperleft` values become the same, where the intended behavior would be that each `LowerRight` and `UpperLeft` Dot should take a different value for each instance of a single `Trace` in the array.

Where is my mistake in this code?
[Debug MSExcel2007 file Link with all the VBA code and class definitions](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xxZjxeEASqgpRTbfRSdAG4mjNJigOah1?usp=sharing)

Further investigation lead me to find that in the VBA module MainMod Sub FillClassDataSet the instance definition for variable object
`Set currentPoint = New cls__Dot
Set currentTrace = New cls_Trace`
,If I displaced, the currentTrace definition within the i loop, then I will create a new instance of that variable for each i iteration. This will correct the problem. The code then works fine. I am now at the level where I have to understand why this is. It should not work any better because embeded in the `cls_Trace` class definition there is already a `.copy` function which is suppose to take care of making sure a new instance of that trace is created.

Furthermore, within the `cls_DataSet class Public Sub AppendTrace`, there is here too a `.copy` call when that new trace instance is added to the Array.

So now the question is :  Why must a new instance be created when within my class definition I do create a new one systematically ?

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Provide the complete code along with the code where you use your classes. Do you use Option Explicit? If not, try to use it.

Comment: @Dee  :  I edited my question and added a link to the EXCEL file. The code compile as expected. Thanks

Comment: Where are `clsRange` and `clsCircle`? In your excel workbook are different classes, except `cls__Dot`.

Comment: @dee : I re-edited my question. Sorry for the mismatch. I wanted to render my code more readable by editing some of the naming, and did not update my question. The EXCEL file is the correct code, and the text above reflect that code. I'll be more vigilant in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand it, sorry. What you can do is: make a simple model of your problem and post a new question. In this question there it should be possible to reproduce the problem. Only so the users here can answer the question.